# Librerias no reconocidas en proyecto JAVA error: package es.mityc.firmaJava.libreria.xades does not exist

Tags: java, maven

He copiado un proyecto desde el repositorio https://github.com/joselo/sri, para lo cual uso Visual Code, usando las extensiones necesarias, pero no reconoce algunas de las librerias. He usado Maven para la configuración del sitio pero tampoco lo he logrado. Actualmente el árbol de archivos esta como se muestra en la imagen:
[image: Árbol de proyecto]

Al intentar generar el archivo .jar mediante el uso de JAR Builder de Visual Code (Ctrl + Alt + P); me salen estos errores:
[image: 2 de 18 errores]

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar le agradecería infinitamente.

Comment: pareciera como si no se hubiesen descargado las dependencias del proyecto

Comment: [Maven usa un archivo `POM.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) donde tienen que estar declaradas las dependencias del proyecto. Verifica ese archivo. Supongo que está todo configurado correctamente. Aquí tienes la [referencia completa](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) sobre POM. Sin conocer eso, trabajar con Maven puede ser un calvario.

Comment: Ya lo había intentado antes pero estoy tratando otra vez, Maven si reconoció las librerías de MITyCLibXADES, pero por alguna razón el proyecto no reconoce algunas importaciones que están dentro.

Comment: Si estás usando Maven, usa POM.xml para declarar todas las dependencias. Esa es su finalidad.

Comment: Asi es, pero el proyecto en si debería funcionar sin Maven, preferiblemente.

Comment: Si no usas una herramienta que gestione las dependencias (como Maven), entonces tienes que identificar las librerías, descargártelas de la web y configurar tu proyecto para que las meta en su classpath. Y, naturalmente, las librerías de las que dependan estas librerías. Y así sucesivamente. Bienvenido al "jar hell".

Comment: Jajaja gracias por la bienvenida, pues estoy usando una extensión para Visual llamada Maven for Java, Java Extension Pack y todas las que me recomendaba el IDE, el proyecto ya incluye los archivos jar a la "antigua", si fuera posible que alguien replique el uso de este repositorio que en realidad no es mas que copiar y generar el archivo .jar;  https://github.com/joselo/sri.

Comment: Si el proyecto debería funcionar sin Maven, entonces ¿por qué compatibilizas con Maven?, no le veo sentido a eso. En ese caso tendrías que olvidar Maven e incluir las librerías a mano, como bien dice @SJuan76. Si aprendes a configurar bien tu proyecto Maven te facilitará el tedioso proceso de descargar/incluir las librerías a mano y además es mucho más fácil mantener tu proyecto actualizado con las últimas versiones de los archivos de cada librería. Es cuestión de dedicarle un poco de tiempo, aprender cómo funciona, configurar adecuadamente y luego irás sobre ruedas.

Comment: Precisamente porque me parece que ahora usan Maven casi como un estándar, hace años que no programo en Java y pues me pareció una buena solución, sin embargo luego de una semana sin soluciones intentando con Netbeans y Eclipse algo me han enseñado sobre proyectos Maven, el proyecto como tal no requiere uso de Maven. ¿Alguien me puede decir que le falta al proyecto para funcionar?

Comment: si no agregas tus archivos de configuracion como por ejemplo el pom.xml, no podremos ayudarte